# Image holder correct aspect ratio even before loading image (so there's no shift in content when it loads)

Tags: java, android, xml

When the user clicks on an article in the list, and is taken to the article detail page (normal "read the article" type page), the image area is small, then, when the image gets loaded, it pops larger... just like HTML does if you forget to specify height and width.

I'm keeping the original image's height and width in my sqlite database.  Can I use this info to somehow set the ratio ahead of time, so it doesn't shift the content when the page loads?

**Note:** I'm currently asking another related question about best XML for a full-width article image:  [Photo: wrap_content, but max_width = layout width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615167/photo-wrap-content-but-max-width-layout-width)

Is it even worth messing with code for this kind of thing, or just leave it to XML and be ok with the content shift?

My current XML for the imageView:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/article_photo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/super_light_gray"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/articlePhoto"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:padding="1dp"/>
```